# Unable to Add NTP servers in ESX Server

Tags: esxi

While adding the ntp server received the following error:

Cannot change the host configuration:

Call "HostDateTimeSystem.UpdateConfig" for object "dateTimeSystem" on ESXi  failed.

Answer (score 0):

When configuring a time configuration on an ESXi 4.1 you could get the error:

```
Call "HostDateTimeSystem.UpdateConfig" for object "dateTimeSystem" on ESXi failed.
```

We get this error through `vCenter` or on the host himself. Additionally we've noticed that the file `/etc/ntp.conf` is empty.
When editing this file, the contents remains empty.

The solution which worked for us, is to delete this file and to recreate it from scratch.

Example contents:

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict 127.0.0.1
server 0.be.pool.ntp.org
server 1.be.pool.ntp.org
driftfile /etc/ntp.drift
```

Now we can alter the configuration from `vCenter` like all other systems

Orginal [link](http://www.paessens.org/blog/index.php/vsphere/128-unable-to-configure-ntp-on-vmware-esxi-4-1)